# Questions about Edge-Node Incidence Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, directed-graphs

If $A$ is an edge-node incidence matrix for a directed graph, then:

- Each row has exactly one $-1$ entry and $+1$ entry
- $dim(Nul(A))$ is the number of independent loops in the directed graph

Would both of these statements be true? I'm especially unsure about the second one because I'm confused about whether an independent loop is another word for connected component. I know that the second statement would be true if we were talking about the number of connected components.

Comment: To clarify the notations: usually the incidence matrix $I \in \mathcal{M}_{n,m}$  ($n$ the number of vertices and $m$ the number of edges) is defined as: "each column represents an arc, $I_{r,c}=-1 $ if the arc $r$ leaves $c$ and $I_{r,c}=1 $ if the arc $r$ ends in $c$. Then there is exactly one $1$ and one $-1$ per column since each edge has one starting- and one end-vertex (I guess you're using the transpose convention, in which case the answer to your first question is "yes"), a vertex can be the origin/end of several edges, so there might be several $-1$/$1$ on a row.

Comment: Regarding the second part, it is known that, for a non-directed graph, if you look to the (directed) incidence matrix of an arbitrary orientation, then its rank is $n-k$ where $n$ is the number of vertices and $k$ the number of connected components. Furthermore, (still in the undirected case) a base of the null space coincides with a base of the cycle space (loop has a specific sens, an edge from a vertex to itself).
The case of directed graphs seems more complicated, but I've find https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.09118.pdf as a reference (with some pointers to the undirected case also)